# How do I remove this Coating from the PCB?

Tags: pcb

This is a PCB from a Washing Machine. I am interested in getting some parts out of it. So what is this Coating and what will be the best way to remove it?

It can't be simply pulled like Glue from glue gun, it is quite sticky after 14-15 years and I don't have anything to heat it around except soldering iron.

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to embed the image?

Comment: Trying yeah. It says too large!

Comment: Reduce the size. I use Irfanview for manipulating images like those from my camera. It's free.

Comment: That's resin. But given the price and amount of resin remover needed, you simply don't remove it.

Comment: Test what you can achieve with hot air, boiling water and normal electric owen. Only have some old tin can.

Comment: I can't imagine any washing machine component is worth it, to remove that gunk. I suggest you have a look at what-ever-you-need costs if you buy it. Unless you have a seen a solid piece of gold under there?

Comment: Second hand and possibly worn out components subject to damage on extraction and illegibility of part type/number/value = complete waste of time.

Comment: I wish there was a solid peice of Gold underneath :D

Comment: Does it mean it is as good as trash? Should I leave the question right here or delete since I don't have anything to do now!

Comment: https://www.smooth-on.com/category/urethane-resin/ YOu can possibly remove it soaking it in some toxic paint remover for a few days.. but whether what's left will be any good after is another story. If you can get some cheap and are going to throw it away anyway.... don't be surprised if the plastic parts disappear too though.